# Youtube kids api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Do [youtube-kids](https://kids.youtube.com/) provides search api that will only return you-tube kids video?

Can I use existing you-tube [api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) to list/search the you-tube kids video? Youtube-kids app only provides content that is child-friendliness. Can I use  existing api to list/search these content?

Comment: My guess is that if you find the same videos on youtube.com, use the api. If not, you may have to contact youtube, or use their product forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/youtube

Comment: @DanielHarrin: Thanks danniel. But my main concern here is searching. By api, how can i list all the videos that are only available in you-tube kids.. In current api, there is no such option to filter video as kids-safe.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the api?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googled around for quite a while and found nothing specific as to a filter or Search API that is for Youtube Kids only. In regards to the [Youtube Search: list API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), there is the `safeSearch` optional parameter that I think you can use instead. As per the docs:

> The `safeSearch` parameter indicates whether the search results should include restricted content as well as standard content.

There are 3 possible values: `moderate`, `none`, and `strict`. I'd suggest the [Education Feed](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_education) but it's already been deprecated, and I think `safeSearch` is the one they use to replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [safeSearch](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#safeSearch) parameter as 'strict'. This is most likely what YouTube Kids uses.